# How to use the Gentleman's MBA?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature

Old Spice published a D&D 3.5 class called "the Gentleman" as part of a promotion (available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mqawllBh142wrtTUuKtR5zpKHo0as6Ik/view) at the time of writing).

At level 19 the Gentleman gains his MBA. The class feature is described as:

> At 19th level, the Gentleman earns his MBA and can now solve complex organizational problems.

As a GM, how can I adjudicate this ability? What kind of check (if any) is appropriate for solving a "complex organizational problem"?

Comment: I don’t see any way to answer this question that isn’t just offering personal opinion, so, unfortunately, voting to close this as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @KRyan Although the class is clearly silly, someone may have experience with it and could back-up an answer with their experience. Outside of this class, someone may have experience incorporating business-like situations into their game. Pathfinder has several archetypes based on that premise, so I imagine that *someone* is playing a game that way.

Comment: I agree with the closure. There's no problem here to solve, nor a question with a best or correct answer available. It's a sweepingly-defined joke feature in a for-fun joke class and we could discuss for days the possible ways to handle it with no right answer, and arguably no altogether wrong answers. That there may be answers available backed up by subjective experience doesn't make a best or correct answer available, so it'd be more like a survey of ideas: “here's how I'd personally do it.”

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is the level 20 ability for this class: "At 20th level, the Gentleman ascends to a higher plane of existence, becoming a being of pure energy. The Gentleman loses all skills, attributes, and abilities. The Gentleman may privately communicate with the GM to make anything explode at will." This is clearly a joke class, and would not work in any remotely serious adjucation of the rules.

Comment: We have an level 11 in our group who plays quite serious so I would really like to see some ideas. We play serious and it makes tons of fun, besides the level 20 skill he is also not op. Nearly every question here is opinion based because mostly no official rule exists.

Comment: @Doomenik You're free to post a question regarding your actual situation and problem. (If you haven't tried to use the lv19 ability in game yet and found it difficult to rule on, then you should wait until you encounter an actual problem—you might not, and it you do, the details of your difficulty are paramount.) As regards questions: we have lots that are not opinion based; if every question was purely opinion-based, every question would be closed. The "everything is opinion" maneuver is often used when someone misunderstands what hold/close is for, and it never works.

Comment: @Doomenik Also note that we don't answer "any ideas" questions. Those *are* all primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong *part* of that special ability. *Any* creature with an Intelligence score can solve complex organizational problems (sometimes for small values of each term, of course). The *real* question should be *In* 3.5e *or* Pathfinder *what advantages are offered if a character earns a degree?* (Think of it as if the special ability said, like, "The mutant grows three noses and can now smell flowers if he holds them up to his face"—you could already *do* that second part but, now, hey, 3 extra noses!)